# Como buscar a última data?

Tags: sql, oracle

estou com um problema sobre meu sql, tentei pesquisar e achei alguns tópicos parecidos, porém nenhum possui uma resposta precisa e/ou efetiva sobre o que necessito, mesmo modificando não consegui chegar ao resultado desejado.

O que eu preciso é buscar apenas a última data por requisição/pedido, porém não estou conseguindo...

Segue o básico do meu sql:

```
select num_requisicao, num_pedido, data_fin
from table
```

Esse sql me retorna os dados necessários:

| num_requisicao | num_pedido | data_fin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 261950 | 244239 | 10/10/19 |
| 261950 | 244240 | 10/11/19 |
| 261952 | 244241 | 10/10/19 |
| 261965 | 244293 | 10/12/19 |
| 262324 | 244820 | 10/11/19 |
| 262324 | 244820 | 10/12/19 |
| 262324 | 244820 | 10/01/20 |

Porém eu necessito que seja filtrado para apenas a última data por requisição/pedido. Segue o resultado desejado:

| num_requisicao | num_pedido | data_fin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 261950 | 244239 | 10/10/19 |
| 261950 | 244240 | 10/11/19 |
| 261952 | 244241 | 10/10/19 |
| 261965 | 244293 | 10/12/19 |
| 262324 | 244820 | 10/01/20 |

Ai surge o meu problema em como solucionar isso, pois já tentei de diversas maneiras e não obtive o resultado desejado.

Segue o SQL completo para maior entendimento do problema:

```
select rr.num_requisicao, rr.num_pedido, rr.data_fin
    from (select distinct ss.num_requisicao, ss.num_pedido, ss.cod_fornecedor, ss.desc_fornecedor, ss.mail, ss.ddd, ss.fone, ss.desc_gestor, ss.cod_cc, ss.desc_cc, ss.valor_contrato, ss.valor_atual, ss.valor_pago, ss.data_ini, ss.data_fin, ss.observacao
            from (select tt.*, b.descricao desc_cc
                    from (select uu.*, listagg(su.descr_obs_ped, ' ') within group (order by su.seq_linha_obs) over (partition by uu.num_requisicao, uu.num_pedido, uu.cod_cc, uu.cod_gestor, uu.data_fin) observacao, su.seq_linha_obs seq
                            from (select vv.*, listagg(h.usuario, ' - ') within group (order by vv.num_requisicao, vv.num_pedido, vv.data_fin, vv.cod_gestor) over (partition by vv.num_requisicao, vv.num_pedido, vv.data_fin) desc_gestor
                                    from (select ww.*, o.cod_usuario cod_gestor
                                            from (select xx.num_requisicao, xx.num_pedido, xx.empresa, xx.cod_cc, xx.cod_fornecedor, xx.fornecedor9, xx.fornecedor4, xx.fornecedor2, xx.desc_fornecedor, xx.mail, xx.fone, xx.ddd, sv.data_prev_entr_ini data_ini, sv.data_prev_entr data_fin, 
                                                        sum(coalesce(round((coalesce(sv.qtde_pedida_item, 0) * coalesce(sv.preco_item_comp, 0)), 2), 0)) valor_contrato, 
                                                        sum(coalesce(round((coalesce(sv.qtde_saldo_item, 0) * coalesce(sv.preco_item_comp, 0)), 2), 0))  valor_atual, 
                                                        sum((coalesce(round((coalesce(sv.qtde_pedida_item, 0) * coalesce(sv.preco_item_comp, 0)), 2), 0)) - 
                                                        (coalesce(round((coalesce(sv.qtde_saldo_item, 0) * coalesce(sv.preco_item_comp, 0)), 2), 0))) valor_pago
                                                    from (select yy.*, sw.nome_fornecedor desc_fornecedor, sw.e_mail mail, lpad(sw.telefone_forne, 8, '0') fone, lpad(sw.ddd_celular, 2, '0') ddd
                                                            from (select zz.*, lpad(sx.forn_ped_forne9, 8, '0')||'.'||lpad(sx.forn_ped_forne4, 4, '0')||'.'||lpad(sx.forn_ped_forne2, 2, '0') cod_fornecedor, sx.forn_ped_forne9 fornecedor9, sx.forn_ped_forne4 fornecedor4, sx.forn_ped_forne2 fornecedor2
                                                                    from (select sy.num_requisicao, sy.seq_item_req sequencia, sy.numero_pedido num_pedido, sz.codigo_empresa empresa, sz.ccusto_aplicacao cod_cc
                                                                            from pette.supr_065 sz
                                                                                left join pette.supr_067 sy on sz.num_requisicao = sy.num_requisicao
                                                                            where sz.codigo = 6
                                                                                and sy.situacao <> 0
                                                                                and sy.num_requisicao is not null
                                                                                and sy.numero_pedido  is not null ) zz
                                                                        left join pette.supr_090 sx on zz.num_pedido = sx.pedido_compra ) yy
                                                                left join pette.supr_010 sw on yy.fornecedor9 = sw.fornecedor9
                                                                                        and yy.fornecedor4    = sw.fornecedor4
                                                                                        and yy.fornecedor2    = sw.fornecedor2 ) xx
                                                        left join pette.supr_100 sv on xx.num_requisicao = sv.num_requisicao
                                                                                and xx.sequencia         = sv.seq_item_req
                                                                                and xx.num_pedido        = sv.num_ped_compra
                                                                                and xx.cod_cc            = sv.centro_custo
                                                    where sv.qtde_saldo_item is not null
                                                    group by xx.num_requisicao, xx.num_pedido, xx.empresa, xx.cod_cc, xx.cod_fornecedor, xx.fornecedor9, xx.fornecedor4, xx.fornecedor2, xx.desc_fornecedor, xx.mail, xx.fone, xx.ddd, sv.data_prev_entr_ini, sv.data_prev_entr ) ww
                                                left join pette.orcm_001 o on ww.empresa = o.cod_empresa
                                                                        and ww.cod_cc    = o.centro_custo
                                            where o.flag_orcamento = '1' ) vv
                                        left join pette.hdoc_030 h on vv.cod_gestor = h.codigo_usuario
                                                                and h.empresa       = vv.empresa ) uu
                                left join pette.supr_120 su on uu.num_pedido = su.pedido_compra ) tt
                        left join pette.basi_185 b on tt.cod_cc = b.centro_custo ) ss
            where ss.num_requisicao is not null
            group by ss.num_requisicao, ss.num_pedido, ss.cod_fornecedor, ss.desc_fornecedor, ss.mail, ss.ddd, ss.fone, ss.desc_gestor, ss.cod_cc, ss.desc_cc, ss.valor_contrato, ss.valor_atual, ss.valor_pago, ss.data_ini, ss.data_fin, ss.observacao, ss.seq
            order by ss.num_requisicao, ss.num_pedido, ss.data_fin, ss.desc_gestor ) rr
        left join siip.contratos cc on rr.num_requisicao = cc.num_requisicao
                                and rr.num_pedido        = cc.num_pedido
                                and rr.data_fin          = cc.data_final
    order by rr.num_requisicao, rr.num_pedido, rr.data_fin--, rr.desc_gestor
```

Comment: Parece uma questão simples de `max` com `group by`, tipo assim: `select num_requisicao, num_pedido, max(data_fin) as data_fin
from table group by num_requisicao, num_pedido`.

Comment: Concordo, pensei ser uma questão simples, inseri essa opção até sobre a linha 7 `select xx.num_requisicao, xx.num_pedido, max(sv.data_prev_entr) data_fin` com o group by, etc. Porém mesmo assim continua trazendo todas as datas quando a requisição e o pedido são iguais...

Comment: Acredito que você só fez no local errado, teria que fazer na parte que usa o alias de tabela `rr`, na primeira linha e o group by seria inserido como penúltima linha, antes do order by, também com o `rr`.

Comment: Também já coloquei, e o **Oracle** me solicita a inclusão do `rr.data_fim` na cláusula `group by`,  com isso não me apresenta o resultado desejado, pois continua trazendo todas as datas para a requisição e o pedido.

Comment: Já que aparentemente fui bloqueado para responder minha própria pergunta (com a solução), segue o comentário com a solução do problema. Após algumas revisões e avaliação sobre o artigo [**Select Rows with Maximum Value on a Column in SQL Server**](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/select-rows-with-maximum-value-on-a-column-in-sql-server/). foi possível encontrar a solução. O artigo basicamente se refere novamente a utilização do `MAX Attribute`,  avaliando o artigo me deparei com a subconsulta como até então não tinha realizado.

Comment: Portando para ciência da resolução do problema segue como ficaria o SQL simplificado: `select * from (select tb1.num_requisicao, tb1.num_pedido, tb1.data_fin from table1 tb1) where tb1.data_fin = (select max(tb2.data_prev_entr) from table2 tb2 where tb2.num_requisicao = tb1.num_requisicao and tb2.num_ped_compra = tb1.num_pedido)`.

Comment: Adicionando o respectivo código sobre o SQL completo foi obtido o resultado desejado, porém ainda não consegui compreender o motivo de não conseguir adicionar apenas o `MAX Attribute` sobre a 1º linha do SQL com o `Group By`, visto que conforme informado no comentário, não haveria funcionado. Se alguém souber informar o motivo para ciência, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -2):

Cara sei um pouco de SQL mas pelo que vi, vc não teria que que agrupar primeiro por num_pedido e não por num_requisição?
Imagino que não precise agrupar por todas essas colunas como fez também.
Para ter a última data use a função max(data_fin).
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa, não entendi direito sua dúvida, mas necessitaria que me fosse apresentada apenas a ultima data do contrato (requisição/pedido), atualmente me apresenta todas as datas de edição... Essas colunas estão agrupadas para fim do php, por isso da necessidade de todos esses agrupamentos, etc, porém agora que surgiu essa nova solicitação estou me quebrando para voltar atrás no sql, chegando a essa questão...

Comment: Imagino algo assim: 
`Select max(num_requisicao), num_pedido, max(data_fin)
From table
Group By num_pedido`

Comment: Compreendi, porém conforme respondi ao @benilson o Oracle me solicita a inclusão do rr.data_fim, nesse caso também é solicitado o rr.num_requisicao na cláusula group by, com isso não me apresenta o resultado desejado, pois continua trazendo todas as datas para a requisição e o pedido.